# SVG markers with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, svg

How do you SVG-marker layers in PyQGIS? I'm importing a vector layer and want to display it with SVG-markers. 
It seems that QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayerV2 does not exist in PyQGIS...

Comment: can you show your code